# Object Reference error - Struct @ WM_DEVICECHANGE

Tags: c#

I am almost getting ready with my program, which I thought runs pretty smoothly. I just happened to realise, at checking usb-arrival, A lot of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is thrown at me on reading the structure that should arrive with the winmsg. I get 3-4 Nullreference errors on plugging and on pulling the usb.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const int WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0x0219;
    private const int DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000;
    private const int DBT_DEVICEREMOVALCOMPLETE = 0x8004;
    private const int DBT_DEVTYPVOLUME = 0x00000002;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {

        if (m.Msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("trying");
                DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol = (DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME));

                if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL) && (vol.dbcv_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYPVOLUME))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("usb in");
                    //NewStickArrived(DriveMaskToLetter(vol.dbcv_unitmask).ToString());
                }
                if ((m.WParam.ToInt32() == DBT_DEVICEREMOVALCOMPLETE) && (vol.dbcv_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYPVOLUME))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("usb out");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] //Same layout in mem
    public struct DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME
    {
        public int dbcv_size;
        public int dbcv_devicetype;
        public int dbcv_reserved;
        public int dbcv_unitmask;
    }

}
```

}

You also need following to try this example:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

I guess it could be at 1. I am doing something wrong with the struct, as I do not yet know much about them, or 2. sometimes this "[...]Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam[...]" does not fit into the structure...

Thanks

Comment: Which line(s) does it crash on?

Comment: Well it does not actually crash, in debug mode output window I get this : " A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Ftp.exe" - I think its the line after debug.writeline("trying")